# How to Replace multiple strings using arrayItem in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, string, replace

[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdz6p.png)

Here is my code, here i am changing arrayItem.replace("\u001bE", "") my problem is i want to change for another string also "\x1B-1" -->  how to declare this in my code replacing multiple strings at a time.

```
               const file = files[0];
               let reader = new FileReader();
                const fruits = [];
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    const file = e.target.result;
                    const lines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
                    //console.log(lines.length);
                    textarea.value = lines.join('\n');
                    lines.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
                        //console.log(arrayItem.replace("\u001bE", "<b>"));
                        var arr1 = arrayItem.replace("\u001bE", "<b>");
                        var arr2 = arr1.replace("\u001bF", "</b>");
                        fruits.push(arr2);
                    });
                    console.log(fruits.length);
                    if (parseInt(fruits.length) > 0) {
                        console.log(fruits);
                        txtreplace.innerHTML = fruits;
                    }
                };
                reader.onerror = (e) => alert(e.target.error.name);
                reader.readAsText(file);

            });
        }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're asking but you can chain multiple calls to replace like this:

```
var arr1 = arrayItem.replace("\u001bE", "<b>").replace("\x1B-1", "<something>");
```